Develop a react application from Docker
I want to develop react application but i don't have node and npm(Unable to install because i've restriction). I've decided to use docker. But whenever i did changes it's not reflecting.
This is my Dockerfile
# Use an official Node runtime as a parent image
FROM node:14

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Install `create-react-app` globally
RUN npm install -g create-react-app

# Create a new React app
RUN create-react-app my-app

# Change working directory to the new React app
WORKDIR /app/my-app

# Install serve to serve the app
RUN npm install -g serve

#RUN npm install npm-watch
RUN npm install --save-dev nodemon

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Build the React app
RUN npm run build

# Serve the React app
CMD ["serve", "-s", "build"]

# Expose port 3000 to the outside world
EXPOSE 3000


docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  react-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    command: npm start


I'm modifying Docker's App.js, but the changes aren't showing up in the browser.
Whenever i did the changes inside docker it should reflect it on the browser.

Your volumes are obscuring everything in the image with what's on your host computer. Try running it without the volumes.

What restrictions exactly are you running into, that you can't just install Node?  There are some serious downsides to trying to coerce Docker into acting like a local development environment: you can't directly access tools like npm, you need special IDE support, and there are frequent SO questions about bind mounts not correctly synching files.  The Node runtime is very commonplace and if you need it to do your job then you should be able to get it installed.

i think what you need here is to use dev container.
Using dev container, you can specify the dependencies you want in your environment via a configuration file very similar to docker-compose.yaml . Your application can be launched in this dockerize environment and you can map between the port of your application in the container and a port on your machine.
You can find some documentation here : vscode , intellij , overview

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

@wohlstad thanks you, I've added some detail to my answer
